# How does a beaker of water heats up

Tags: atomic-physics

It is kind of a silly question to ask.But I was wondering that when you heat a beaker of water,the water molecules vibrate more.But what type of forces causes the water molecules to move faster and collide more??Does the temperature of water increases due to electronic transitions in the water molecules and releasing IR radiation in the process??
Does IR radiation released from the beaker heating up,causes electronic transitions in the water molecules??
Plz forgive me if these questions sound silly :(

Comment: Not silly at all...

Comment: The molecules of the hot plate vibrate too.  The molecules of the beaker vibrate.   _Temperature_ is just another name for the average kinetic energy of the vibrating molecules.  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/temper.html#c1  When molecules collide with one another, they transfer kinetic energy from one to the other---sharing it all around.   That's how heat is _conducted_.

Comment: If temperature is the average kinetic energy of water molecules then what makes the water warm during heating??

Comment: I thought that IR waves are responsible for the warming up of water

Answer (score 0):

If you place a beaker of water on a hotplate, there is *some* heating of the water by IR from the heating element (even if it is not so hot as to be glowing red).   The mechanism for this kind of heating is that the water molecules rotate to try to align with the electromagnetic waves.   The waves are changing rapidly, so the rotations of the water molecules oscillate.   Thus, kinetic energy is transferred from the wave to the molecules.   These molecules transfer the energy to surrounding molecules through collisions.   The collisions transfer both angular and linear velocity, with more and more linearity as the energy spreads out from where it was absorbed.

However, most of the heat transferred by the heating element is not by IR, as you can see by heating water in a steel pan and water in a beaker.   The water in the pan will, I believe, heat even faster than in the beaker.   This is because most the heat transfer is by direct physical collisions between fast moving molecules on the surface of the heating element and on the surface of the pan or beaker, and then between the pan or beaker and the water.

Comment: If temperature is the average kinetic energy of water molecules then what makes the water warm during heating??I thought that IR waves are responsible for the warming up of water during heating

Comment: Yes, temperature is the average kinetic energy the water molecules, so if we increase their average speed, we increase their average kinetic energy.  My answer says yes, IR radiation CAN speed them up and DOES speed them up.  But my answer also says that IR is not the only way to speed up the molecules.